# Linq Lambda expression for below sql in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, linq, lambda, subquery, linq-group

I have this existing Sql statement:

```
Select Count(ordid),isnull(prcsts,'NOT STARTED')
from lwp
where lwp in( Select max(Id) from lwp group by ordid)
group by prcsts
```

I want to convert to use linq-to-sql, but I'm can't figure out how to handle the `group by` expression in the sub query. How can I do this?

I am using Entity Framework where I have a method to get the list of lwp. I did only part of it.

```
Entitydb.lwpmethod
        .GetList
        .Where(Function(F) F.ID = **Max(Function(O)  O.ordid**)
        .GroupBy(Function(F) F.prcsts)
        .Select(Function(F) New With {.A = F.Count, .B = F.Key})
        .ToList
```

I am unable to write the group by subquery in the max function.

Comment: `lwp in (max(id))`? Are you sure it's gonna work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, that's not an `in`, that's an `=` since `max()` returns a single element. Also your sql query has `lwp` in the `where` clause, you probably typo'd `id`. With that in mind, what you want is something like:

```
.Where(row=>row.ID=Entitydb.lwpmethod.GetList()
                                     .Where(r=>r.ordid=row.ordid)
                                     .Max(r=>r.ID))
```

C# code, but you get the idea.

By the way this looks like it's selecting the last row. Why not just sort by `id` descendently and take the first element?

Comment: Thank You it worked, I was confused regarding in and "=". I think the best approach is to use the first ID. I will try that. Thanks for the advise.